# The Event component keeps calling componentDidMount but never load at all

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

There are 3 bottom tabs in my `react native 0.59` app with `react navigation 3.7`. The tabs are `Event`, `Group` and `Contact`. `Event` is the initial tab.

[image]

After initial loading, I click `Group` tab and the screen is as below:

[image]

There are 2 groups HT and MKL shown. After I click one group, either HT or MKL, this should load `Event` component. The problem is that after clicking a group, `Event` is never loaded. On both app and server monitoring screen, there are crazy loading `Event` and `Group` non stop. The screen is stuck at `Group` and  stops responding to any click. I have no clue about this behavior as `Event` module has been fully tested and `Group` is newly added.

Here is the onPress code in `Group` module:

```
async _onPress(id) {
  try {
    console.log("saved group id in Group : ", id);
    await helper.setMyValue("group_id", id.toString());
    //update group_id in App.js
    this.props.updateGroup(id);  //<<<===this causes the problem
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error in saving group_id to local disk", err);
  };
  this.props.navigation.goBack();
  //this.props.navigation.navigate("Event"); //, {group_id:element1.id});
}
```

What the above onPress does is to save the `id` user clicked and call `updateGroup` to update the parent's group_id and call `goBack` which is `Event` component.

The `componentDidMount` in `Event` is:

```
async componentDidMount(){
      this._isMounted = true;

      if (!this.props.group_id) {
        alert("Select a group");
        return;
      };
      try {
        //retrieving token
        let result = this.state.token;
        if (!result) {
          result = await helper.getJwtToken();
           if (this._isMounted) this.setState({
             token: result
           });  
        };

        //console.log("secure store : ", result);
        if (!result) {
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup");
          return;
        };

        this.refreshData(result);

        //refresh data after goBack()
        this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
          'willFocus', () => {
            this.refreshData(result);
          }
        );

        //get user
        let myself = this.state.user;
        if (!myself)  {
          myself = await helper._getUser(result.password, result.username);
          if (this._isMounted) this.setState({
             user: myself
           });  
        };

        console.log("out of did mount event", this.state);
      }
      catch (err) {
        console.log("服务器错误(et)，请再试一次！", err);
        this.props.navigation.navigate.goBack(); //("Event");
        return;

      };
```

Here is the app console output of in `Event` componentDidMount:

```
09-19 20:16:44.551 21659 21743 I ReactNativeJS: 'event url : ', 'http://192.168.2.133:3000/api/events/active?group_id=1&_group_id=1&_device_id=0cfce7b7e86fa397&_timezone=America%2FLos_Angeles'
09-19 20:16:44.552 21659 21743 I ReactNativeJS: 'out of did mount event', { activeEvents: [],

    }
```

UPDATE:

The problem is caused by `this.updateGroup(id)` which updates the state of group_id in `App.js`

```
updateGroup = (group_id) => {
    if (this._isMounted) this.setState({group_id:group_id});
  };
```

It is passed in to `Group` as a props in `App.js`:

```
const GroupWithSelf = (props) => (<Group {...props} myself={data.myself} token={data.result} updateGroup={this.updateGroup} updateToken={this.updateToken} />);
```

Not sure why this method causes racing.

Comment: Did you try doing it with navigate instead of goBack? I don't think bottomTabNavigator has that function

Comment: "there are crazy loading Event and Group non stop and will not stop"  you mean that  async componentDidMount is called many times ?

Comment: `Auticcat`, yes, used both `this.props.navigation.navigate("Event") and `goBack()`. They are all the same. It seems to me that those line was not actually executed

Comment: `Eran`, you are right. like getting into a infinite loop.

Comment: Solved the racing problem by introducing a counter in `Group` and only execute `updateGroup()` only once.